# Parsing command line arguments containing dictionaries

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to pass command line arguments to a python that contain dictionaries like so:

```
python server.py --keys '{"0x11": "f1.bin", "0x21": "f2.bin"}' --binaries '{"0x11": "dog.jpg", "0x21": "apple.jpg"}' -d '100' -p '1234'
```

I want to be able to convert these string representations of dictionaries to actual python dictionaries.

When I print out the argv parameter in my main function, I get a list that looks like this:

```
['--keys', "'{0x11:", 'f1.bin,', '0x21:', "f2.bin}'", '--binaries', "'{0x11:", 'cat.jpg,', '0x21:', "kitten.jpg}'", '-d', "'100'", '-p', "'1234'"]
```

This is not the desired output. For example, notice the dictionaries' keys no longer have quotation marks around them. Because of this, I can't use the `json` or `ast` packages to convert the string representations of the dictionaries to actual dictionaries. I would like if the entire string representation of the dictionaries were a single element in the list and for their structure to be preserved.

I've tried using the `optparse` package, however, this does not help either. Here is how I tried to do it:

```
def main(argv):

    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('--keys')
    parser.add_option('--binaries')
    parser.add_option('-d')
    parser.add_option('-p')

    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    print(argv)
    print(options)
    print(args)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
['--keys', "'{0x11:", 'f1.bin,', '0x21:', "f2.bin}'", '--binaries', "'{0x11:", 'cat.jpg,', '0x21:', "kitten.jpg}'", '-d', "'100'", '-p', "'1234'"]
{'keys': "'{0x11:", 'binaries': "'{0x11:", 'd': "'100'", 'p': "'1234'"}
['f1.bin,', '0x21:', "f2.bin}'", 'cat.jpg,', '0x21:', "kitten.jpg}'"]
```

Is there a simple way to achieve my desired output? Or do I need to write my own code to alter the elements of argv to look like how I want before using `json` or `ast`?

---

**NOTE**
Maurice's solution is perfect. It caused a little bit of trouble at first, until he noticed my problem was actually only occurring on Windows. On Windows, We must surround the dictionaries by double quotes, and escape the inner double quotes like this:

```
python server.py --keys "{\"0x11\": \"f1.bin\", \"0x21\": \"f2.bin\"}" --binaries"{\"0x11\": \"dog.jpg\", \"0x21\": \"apple.jpg\"}" -d '100' -p '1234'
Huge thanks to him, because I never would have figured this issue out on my own.
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse) (optparse is deprecated), options can have a types (`int`, `str`, ...). But you can use `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval` as `type` to parse the JSON string:

```
import ast
import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='JSON TEST')
parser.add_argument('--keys', type=ast.literal_eval)
parser.add_argument('--binaries', type=json.loads)
parser.add_argument('-d', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-p', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Calling from CLI:

```
python server.py --keys '{"0x11": "f1.bin", "0x21": "f2.bin"}' --binaries '{"0x11": "dog.jpg", "0x21": "apple.jpg"}' -d '100' -p '1234'
```

Out:

```
Namespace(binaries={'0x11': 'dog.jpg', '0x21': 'apple.jpg'}, d='100', keys={'0x11': 'f1.bin', '0x21': 'f2.bin'}, p='1234')
```

**Note:**
On Windows you need to escape the quotes within the JSON string:

```
python server.py --keys "{\"0x11\": \"f1.bin\", \"0x21\": \"f2.bin\"}" --binaries "{\"0x11\": \"dog.jpg\", \"0x21\": \"apple.jpg\"}" -d '100' -p '1234'
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: This gives me the following output: `'{0x11:^SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: Copy and Pasting the CLI command you mentioned in your question works fine for me on Python27/38 and 39.

Comment: I'm currently running python 3.7

Comment: If I change the type in the first call to parse.add_argument to json.loads, the error changes to ```server.py: error: argument --keys: invalid loads value: "'{0x11:"
```

Comment: Can you show what you're executing on CLI (the whole command) ?

Comment: ```python server.py --keys '{"0x11": "f1.bin", "0x21": "f2.bin"}' --binaries '{"0x11": "dog.jpg", "0x21": "apple.jpg"}' -d '100' -p '1234'```

Comment: It's the same command included in the original post

Comment: Are you on Windows ?

Comment: Yes I am. I am trying to run this command in the terminal provided in the PyCharm IDE, could that make a difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225694/discussion-between-maurice-meyer-and-mari).

Comment: The same error happens if I run it in the command prompt as well.